# How to extract values from nested lists in a manner compatible with descriptive stats (R)

Tags: r

I've been using `lapply` to run 1,000 GLS's (`pgls` in `caper`) on 1,000 different phylogenetic trees. I want to create a table with the average and min/max of various values (like the slope and p-values) from within the resulting list. So far I have been using `lapply` to extract lists of the values I want in the hopes I could run codes like `max` and `min` on said lists. As an example, to get the p-values from every equation I ran, I have used `p.values<-lapply(glslist,FUN=function(x)summary(x)$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"])`The output from this code looks like this:

```
head(p.values)
$tree_4885
    (Intercept) Habitat.Breadth 
      0.0000000       0.2369276 

$tree_7452
    (Intercept) Habitat.Breadth 
      0.0000000       0.2369275 

$tree_0747
    (Intercept) Habitat.Breadth 
      0.0000000       0.2369275 

$tree_6343
    (Intercept) Habitat.Breadth 
      0.0000000       0.2369275 

$tree_6089
    (Intercept) Habitat.Breadth 
      0.0000000       0.2369275 

$tree_7216
    (Intercept) Habitat.Breadth 
      0.0000000       0.2369276
```

When I try to run an equation like `max` on this list I get the following error `Error in max(p.values) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument`
How do I format my extraction code so that I can get the values I want in a list I can run descriptive stats on?
New R user, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just want `max(unlist(p.values))` ?

Comment: Alternatively you might want to extract the key bits into a matrix by using `sapply` instead of `lapply` - e.g. - `sapply(glslist,FUN=function(x) coef(summary(x))[,"Pr(>|t|)"] )` or even consider the *broom* package which makes some of these things nice - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html

Comment: Another option to get the max Habitat.Breadth is`max(unlist(map(p.values, pluck, "Habitat.Breadth")))`. Or, to get a dataframe of the Habitat.Breadth values, you can use `stack()`, i.e. `stack(map(p.values, pluck, "Habitat.Breadth"))`

Comment: Or in base R style, `sapply(glslist,FUN=function(x) coef(summary(x))["Habitat.Breadth", "Pr(>|t|)"] )` to select the specific variable.

Comment: @thelatemail these are all great thank you for the help!

Comment: @jared_mamrot this is very helpful thank you!